# Path to executable in Windows Firewall rule contains random number after colon

Tags: windows-firewall, storage-spaces

When I run an executable located on Storage Spaces disk that requires incoming network connections, the Windows firewall incorrectly determines the full executable path.

- the actual path is `M:\sw\test.exe`
- syntactically incorrect firewall path is `D:3\sw\test.exe`

The rule does not match any running program and thus the `test.exe` is never allowed to receive incoming connections.

The problem can be fixed by editing the rule manually, but I would like to know why this is happening and how to fix it without having to resort to manually editing the firewall rule each time.

[image: p1]
[image: p2]

Comment: Any news about what can cause it ?
I have had a similar issue. I am suspecting a malware trying to divert access authorisation somehow but i have no clue.
I doesn't always happen but when it does i refuse access and the exe still works

Comment: @RR404 good to hear I am not alone, but I can no longer reproduce the problem. I wouldn't worry about malware, this looks more like a bug.

Comment: Have you installed the windows 10 bash terminal ? I thought it might have been that causing issues with pathes

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old thread, but this bug actually exists today. I have experienced it like week ago.

Reinstall of windows did not helped me to solve this problem (which means, that this is some bug carried with the data of partitions itself (partition table?)).

This bug also affects debugging (debugger tries to load debug symbols from those malformed paths, and it can't do it).

I have managed to find solution for me (but I still don't know what exacly was heppening, and i don't know how to apply my fix if malformed paths point to system partition: usually **"C:"**):

1. Go to disk management (run **"diskmgmt.msc"**)
2. Right click on partition to which malformed paths point to (in my case **"D:1"** means partition **"D:"**)
3. Click **"Change Drive Letter and Paths..."**
4. In window that pops up you should see your partition, now click delete and confirm (**this will not delete partition, it will only delete drive letter**, partition will not be seen in windows explorer after that)
5. Right click the same partition again
6. Click **"Change Drive Letter and Paths..."**
7. Assing new letter to this partition (i have assigned **"D:"** again)

After that problem disappeared. If your malformed paths point to system partition, then obviously you have to find another way (maybe running second windows?).

I hope that helps.